# Get captcha image from WebBrowser with alpha, without downloading it

Tags: c#, browser, captcha

I have tried to use clipboard method like this:

```
foreach (IHTMLImgElement img in doc.images)
{    
   if (img.src.Contains(name))
   {
    var imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange) body.createControlRange();
    imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement) img);
    imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
    return (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetImage();
   }
}
```

But it gives me image without alpha.
Without alpha captcha is unreadable.

So, is there any other way to get image from browser?

Comment: I wonder if you'd be prepared to tell us why you want to capture captchas?

Comment: he must work for google

Comment: want to implement algorithm of recognition for study purposes

Comment: ... and then sell it to spammers?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any cookie set only remove that thus you can get the real captcha.